# como puedo obtener la longitud de una coleccion en firestore de firebase?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, javascript-objeto, firestore

Estoy trabajando en una web que permita agregar registros a una coleccion y quiero que el ID del documento sea el numero siguiente al ultimo agregado en la coleccion, es decir, actualmente hay 6 documentos en la coleccion y quiero que el ID del proximo documento a agregar se asigne como 6 de forma automatica, tenia pensado hacerlo obteniendo la longitud de la colleccion y sumarle 1, lo estoy haciendo de la siguiente manera:

```
const collectionRef = collection(db, 'repairStatus')
    console.log(collectionRef)
```

La respuesta es el siguiente objeto en el cual no encuentro la informacion que busco:

```
{
    "converter": null,
    "_query": {
        "path": {
            "segments": [
                "repairStatus"
            ],
            "offset": 0,
            "len": 1
        },
        "collectionGroup": null,
        "explicitOrderBy": [],
        "filters": [],
        "limit": null,
        "limitType": "F",
        "startAt": null,
        "endAt": null,
        "le": null,
        "he": null,
        "Pe": null
    },
    "type": "collection",
    "firestore": {
        "app": {
            "_isDeleted": false,
            "_options": {
                "apiKey": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
                "authDomain": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                "projectId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                "storageBucket": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                "messagingSenderId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                "appId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                "measurementId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
            },
            "_config": {
                "name": "[DEFAULT]",
                "automaticDataCollectionEnabled": false
            },
            "_name": "[DEFAULT]",
            "_automaticDataCollectionEnabled": false,
            "_container": {
                "name": "[DEFAULT]",
                "providers": {}
            }
        },
        "databaseId": {
            "projectId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "database": "(default)"
        },
        "settings": {
            "host": "firestore.googleapis.com",
            "ssl": true,
            "ignoreUndefinedProperties": false,
            "cacheSizeBytes": 41943040,
            "experimentalForceLongPolling": false,
            "experimentalAutoDetectLongPolling": true,
            "experimentalLongPollingOptions": {},
            "useFetchStreams": true
        }
    },
    "_path": {
        "segments": [
            "repairStatus"
        ],
        "offset": 0,
        "len": 1
    }
}
```

cualquier otro metodo para lograr poner como ID el numero siguiente al ultimo documento tambien sirve